# Bulk edit Firefox bookmarks

Tags: sqlite, firefox, bookmarks

The company where I work have changed all corporate URL from `subdomain.domain.com` to `new.domain.com`

I would like to change the subdomain of all my bookmarked sites in Firefox which are a lot.

Is it possible to change all of them in a row instead of manually editing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if there is a better solution but this hack seems to works:

**First locate the bookmarks file:**

- Go to Help -> Troubleshooting Information and then click the "Open Containing Folder" button near "Profile Directory".
- Do a backup copy of places.sqlite.

**Then edit bookmarks:**

- Close Firefox.
- Edit the file places.sqlite with a SQLLite editor of your choice (you can use online tools).
- Execute this SQL statement:

  - UPDATE moz_places SET url = REPLACE(url, 'subdomain.domain.com', 'new.domain.com');
- Save the edited places.sqlite file.
- Open Firefox.